# neo4j all relations to certain depth between 2 sets

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Playing with simple neo4j queries. My base match is :

```
MATCH (:Movie { id: '10' })-[*0..3]-(p:Producer)
RETURN p.id
```

This returns some results, so obviously there are some relations between movie-10 and any producer. Part of the result set is:

```
'producer_12'
'producer_18'
'producer_36'
.........
```

Now I want to return all relations between movie-10 and producer_12 or producer_18 up to 3 hops. I modified my match.

```
MATCH (:Movie { id: '10' })-[*0..3]-(p:Producer)
WHERE p.id IN ['producer_12', 'producer_18']
RETURN p.id
```

And this already doesn't return any value, while I expected producers 12 and 18 to be in the answer. Besides I can't find the way to label the relation. This is not accepted. [r:*0..3].

My final query must be to get all relations between 2 sets (movies 10, 12 or 15) and (producers 12 or 18) for example.

Comment: which version of neo4j are you using? Also can you post some sample data set and the expected result? thanks!

Comment: The `id` property of `:Movie` is really a string?

Comment: it's really a string. this an id that came from import. I can match the author in a simple query like MATCH (m:Movie { id: '10'} ) return m

Comment: Sample data would be very hard. Database is huge.

Comment: I edited my answer, please take a look in the sample data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulated your scenario here.

The sample data:

```
CREATE (movie:Movie {id : '10'})
CREATE (producer12:Producer {id:'producer_12'})
CREATE (producer18:Producer {id:'producer_18'})
CREATE (producer36:Producer {id:'producer_36'})
CREATE (movie)-[:PRODUCTED_BY]->(producer12)
CREATE (movie)-[:PRODUCTED_BY]->(producer18)
CREATE (movie)-[:PRODUCTED_BY]->(producer36)
```

Querying:

```
MATCH (:Movie { id: '10' })-[*0..3]-(p:Producer)
WHERE p.id IN ['producer_12', 'producer_18']
RETURN p.id
```

The result:

```
╒═════════════╕
│"p.id"       │
╞═════════════╡
│"producer_12"│
├─────────────┤
│"producer_18"│
└─────────────┘
```

Probably your `id` property of `:Movie` nodes is not a `string` but an `integer`. So try changing your query to:

```
MATCH (:Movie { id: 10 })-[*0..3]-(p:Producer)
WHERE p.id IN ['producer_12', 'producer_18']
RETURN p.id
```

That is: change `'10'` to `10`.

> Besides I can't find the way to label the relation. This is not
>   accepted. [r:*0..3].

This is because you are not using a type in the relationship. The `:` is only used in conjunction with a type (for example, `[r:SOME_TYPE*0..3]`). So remove the `:`, this way: `[r *0..3]`.

**EDIT:**

From comments:

> About the last sentence: It's still working but it says that "This
>   feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. Binding
>   relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated" –
>   user732456 3 hours ago

Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated since [3.2.0-rc1](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.2-changelog#320-rc1).

According this [pull request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/9160) Cypher queries like:

```
MATCH (n)-[rs*]-() RETURN rs
```

will generate a warning and the canonical way to write the same query is:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]-() RETURN relationships(p) AS rs
```

Comment: About the last sentence: It's still working but it says that "This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated"

Comment: @user732456 I edited my answer explaning it. Please check!

Comment: Just found this out as well :)

Comment: btw I found what was wrong with my query. it was really a string. my producer's names happened to be very close and I misspelled -> A name that seemed to me that was in the result for 3 nodes away in fact was 5 nodes. So the query didn't return any values with where clause. The relationship part of the answer was very helpful to me as well